# Maintain Two Types Of User

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have a requirement where I have to maintain two types of users.

1. A company and all of its users, to manage day-to-day work. And also create public data like showing a few items and related images and set availability for meetings and more.
2. Public user who can see the items, images. and can book the meetings.

Now for the first case, every user is created by official email and password as registeruser endpoint from rest-framework. there is user profile and other company data.

For the second type of user (public), I have to give access for social login as well as login by email/mobile (maybe).

I am confused as how to configure this in the best possible way. the company datas' are important.

Should I create both user types in the same database (differentiating by user types)? or should I use a seprerate database then how to fetch data from two databases (never done this)?  Also to keep my datas safe from unauthorized access.

Or is there a better way to manage all of my requirements which I'm totally unaware of? Like a better approach.

Looking for an explanation from an experienced person.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is creating a custom User model (or even keep the default one) and implement permissions on views/ressource. This can be implemented by groups, for instance, the public group, in which everyone is (can be public or even no groups) and the private group.

Once you can differentiate between your users, you can add a reference to a ressource and its subressource to the group (ForeignKey on the group) and filters necessary queryset laters on your view. On certain view, you can also restrict some endpoints, through permissions.

Another way would be to use Object Permissions.
Anyway here are the ressources :

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/ (and django-guardian for object-level permission)

and

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Also, you can take a look on how it is implemented on a opensource project like Sentry: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/blob/master/src/sentry/api/endpoints/api_applications.py

Comment: Somehow I'm not willing to IMPLEMENT both the logic at the same database, do you have any idea how to deal with this at the database level. btw I'm aware of custom users and permission and this recommended way may be my last option. I have a lot of user groups at the company level.

Comment: You mean having two separate database for storing users ? Well you can have multiple database with django, even for users, but you will have extra logic to know where to query the data.

Comment: my research suggests foreignkey and manytomany fields are not supported across multiple databases,  (there is a hack but I'm not doing that). also we cant have users at multiple databases as users are managed by a settings file. Now I will have to internally post data from one application to another or use the above-mentioned logic.